# zsh completion: duplicate commands

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

Lets say I have an alias for `grep`. When I use `zsh completion`, it will offer grep twice (once as command, once as alias):

```
gr<TAB>
grep
grep
```

I found I can use `ignored-patterns` specifically for `aliases` for `commands` or for `builtins` or `functions`"

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:aliases' ignored-patterns 'grep'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:commands' ignored-patterns 'foo'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:builtins' ignored-patterns 'something'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:functions' ignored-patterns 'something'
```

but there are some completions I need to ignore which are neither of these categories:

```
which coproc
coproc: shell reserved word
```

also, if I have variable defined, it completed the variable:

```
foo=1

fo<TAB>
foo
```

how can I specify "shell reserved words" and variables to be ignored ?

## UPDATE:

after further research, I found the general syntax for zstyle:

```
':completion:<function>:<completer>:<command>:<argument>:<tag>'
```

and what I am looking for is the proper tag name for "reserved word", such as `coproc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a far easier way to get rid of duplicate entries coming from different tags: Put the tags in the same group.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' \
    group-name -command-
```

In any case, the tag for reserved words is…  `reserved-words`. You can see that in the code [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/search?q=reserved-words&type=).